# how to print check with thermal printer

Tags: javascript, printing

how can I print the check with a thermal printer or default printer

```html
<button onclick="printCheck()">print check</button>

<p>
    check body
    ...
</p>

<script>
    function printCheck() {
        window.print()
    }
</script>
```

this code is working but it opens Print Menu. I need print with press button "print check"

Comment: You can not do it. with `window.print()`. You need to look into the WebUSB https://github.com/drffej/webusb.printer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=2021+javascript+print+without+dialog+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<***